# how to get to the slide given a selection

Tags: vsto, powerpoint

I am in the WindowSelectionChange event and I want to get to the slide that the selection is on. Can anyone help me here. I tried casting from the parent of the selection and that threw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your even handler will be passed the current selection as a parameter, eg

```
WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
```

So you can do something like this:

```
With Sel

    Select Case .Type

        Case ppSelectionNone
            MsgBox "Nothing selected. Why did you wake me up?"

        Case ppSelectionShapes
            ' The Selection is a ShapeRange of one or more shapes
            ' The parent of the shaperange gives you a reference
            ' to the slide or slide master
            MsgBox "The current selection is on: " _
                    & .ShapeRange.Parent.Name

        Case ppSelectionSlides
            ' The selection is one or more slides
            ' Use something like this?
            If .SlideRange.Count > 1 Then
                MsgBox "One slide at at time. Please!"
            Else
                MsgBox "You've selected " & .SlideRange(1).Name
            End If

        Case ppSelectionText
            ' Generally:
            MsgBox "You've selected text on " & .TextRange.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name
            ' .Parent is the textrange
            ' .Parent.Parent is the shape
            ' .Parent.Parent.Parent is the slide holding the shape
            ' This will not work for text in table cells in some PPT versions

        Case Else
            MsgBox "ALIENS!  RUN!!!"

    End Select

 End With
```

Note:  it's a good idea to do something like this in the event handler:

Turn event handling off
Call SomeOtherRoutine(Sel)  ' to do the actual work
Turn event handling on

That way you won't have to worry about your other routine inadvertently firing events or about handling other events that occur while your other routine's running.